# Microsoft Chart Controls Legend Item Ordering

Tags: mschart, legend, microsoft-chart-controls

I've got a chart with 8 series - call them S1 through S8. They're in order in the chart's list of series, and they're presented using custom legend items (Legend.CustomItems). Everything works fine, except there seems to be a bug with how items are displayed in the legend when the legend wraps around to a new line.

I'd like the items to be displayed in rows:

```
S1 S2 S3 S4
S5 S6 S7 S8
```

Unfortunately, it seems like when the legend detects that it's going to take two rows, it fills in vertically before horizontally, like so:

```
S1 S3 S5 S7
S2 S4 S6 S8
```

Is there any way to get the items arranged properly? Is this a bug with the controls?

```
var chart = new Chart();
// More chart setup
foreach(var s in chart.Series)
{
    if (simpleLegend) chart.Legends[0].CustomItems.Add(s.Color, s.LegendText);
    else
    {
        var legendItem = new LegendItem();
        // Legend item customization
        chart.Legends[0].CustomItems.Add(legendItem);
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

To make it clear, the issue is with the *layout* of the legend items, not the order. Depending on the length of the legend items, I may end up with this layout:

```
S1 S3 S5 S7 S8
S2 S4 S6
```

Answer (score 4):

You can arrange them in `CustomizeLegend` event.

Add `OnCustomizeLegend="Chart1_CustomizeLegend"` to your Chart markup or bind it in code behind. Then create handler:

```
protected void Chart1_CustomizeLegend(object sender, CustomizeLegendEventArgs e)
{
    //change order of legend items
    var items = e.LegendItems;
    var item = items[1]; //s2
    items.RemoveAt(1);
    items.Insert(2, item);
    item = items[1]; //after removing s2, s3 is now here
    items.RemoveAt(1);
    items.Insert(4, item);
    //etc...
}
```

Or you can create some collection first and fill it by referencing existing legend items in desired order, then clearing `LegendItems` and inserting all items at once. I think you can write it in a way it will be valid for all items number, but I leave it to you ;).

More info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd488245.aspx

*(I know this question is almost 2 years old but maybe someone with same problem (like me today) will find this helpful.)*

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer such an old question! Unfortunately, this doesn't solve my particular problem, as the _order_ of the items in the legend is correct, it's the _layout_ that's incorrect. I don't think I made that clear in my question, though.

Comment: Yes, but that's the way Chart control displays items that are in order you have. So to display them properly you need to change the order to what I suggested above (or even change it while adding items to legend). The problem is if user can change the size of the chart and it's possible that legend items will be in one line and wrong order. Or if series can be added dynamically. I don't know if there is easy way out of this then...