# .Net Chart Control LegendStyle.Row show rows

Tags: c#, .net, mschart, legend, legend-properties

I am trying to get dynamic legend items to display as such (without making the font smaller)

```
Item1       Item2       Item3

Item4       Item5
```

If i set the LegendStyle property to "Table" it displays the items like this:

```
Item1   Item3     Item5

Item2   Item4
```

So I set the LegendStyle propery to "Row" and IsTextAutoFit = false the items are displayed like this:

```
Item1   Item2   Item 3

     ...
```

Please could someone help me with what other settings i will need to set in order to get my legend items to display like option 1.

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3790407/microsoft-chart-controls-legend-item-ordering